# Angular TS SourceMaps Not Working In Chrome Debugger

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Without any change in configuration, I can no longer debug Angular TS files in Chrome, either by setting manual breakpoints in Dev Tools or by `debugger;` statements.  Facts of the situation:

- I am running Angular in `Development`, **not** `Production`
- My `tsconfig` has `"sourceMap": true`
- CSS maps are working properly (see below)
- `debugger;` lines aren't being hit at all
- "Enable JavaScript source maps" is enabled in Dev Tools settings
- I've also tried adding the local directory to Dev Tools, but only the CSS files map.

What's strange, however, is that when I open the app in **Safari, the `debugger;` breakpoints are hit, and I can set manual breakpoints in TS files just fine**.  So that leads me to believe that this is a Chrome issue and not an Angular configuration issue.

[image]
Specs =>
Chrome: Version 75.0.3770.142 (up-to-date as of this post),
Angular: 6.1.2 (Project requirement, so this can't be updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing this all up, I realized the issue was **caused by having another Angular project directory loaded into Dev Tools**.  The automatic mapping was looking at the `src` directory of this other project rather than the current project I was working on.

- The CSS was mapping because the other project uses `.scss` instead of `.css`, so no match was found there
- TS debugging working in Safari because the other project had not been added to Safari Dev Tools

If anyone knows of a way to avoid this problem moving forward, please let me know!  I work on multiple projects simultaneously very frequently, so it would be nice to not have to remove each project when switching to a new one.

Comment: Hi, I think im having the same problem. How exactly did you solve this? I didn't really understand what you meant by having another project directory loaded in dev tools. How would I fix this?

Comment: @lorless check out [this link in the google dev docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/?utm_source=devtools).  I had more than one "Workspace" set up in dev tools, or in other words I had multiple local filesystem directories mapped to the chrome debugger.  E.g. `app.component.ts` is a component in both project A and B.  When loading project B in the debugger though, dev tools says "Oh, well here's `app.component.ts` on the local filesystem, let's use this for debugging", but it's looking at the file from Project A.  Does that make sense?

Comment: And in case is wasn't clear, I resolved by removing the workspace for the project I'm not actively working on.  All this means though is that Chrome Dev tools are no longer looking in that specific local filesystem directory.